# How to align an inline-block horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, alignment, vertical-alignment, css

What is the best/cleanest using `CSS` to align the `#dates div` to the right side of the header, and vertically in the middle.

I tried `float: right`, but that does not allow the `vertical-align`. I want to avoid using floats, so I am using `inline-block`, and using relative positioning. Is there a more correct approach?

I do not like the fact that I have to do a top of 30px, and using trial and error until it centers.

```
<div id="header">
    <a id="logo" href="~/" runat="server">
        <img src="Images/Interface/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    </a>
    <div id="dates">
        <div id="hijri-date">2 Ramadhaan, 1435 AH</div>
        <div id="gregorian-date">Sunday 29 June 2014</div>
    </div>
</div>

#header
{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#logo
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

    #logo img
    {
        vertical-align: bottom; /* to get rid of text descender space underneath image */
    }

#dates
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #696969;
    background: url(Images/Interface/date-icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-position-y: center;
    padding-left: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of css `display:table`:

```css
#header {display:table; width:100%;}
#logo,
#dates {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/F7Nb5/2/)

You may need to give the #dates a width if you want it to be aligned to the right

Comment: Is it possible for a cell to be the width of its contents instead of 50%?

Comment: CSS tables have advantages for this application.  It might help to have a sub-wrapper div around the text block in the right hand table cell, that way you can use text-align right, and no need to worry about the exact table-cell width.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Inline-Blocks**

Using your HTML elements as posted, try the following CSS:

```css
#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 0;
}
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#logo img {
    vertical-align: bottom; 
        /* to get rid of text descender space underneath image */
}
#dates {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
    color: black;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
    background-position: center;
    padding-left: 32px;
}
#header:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Since you have two child elements in `#header`, a left logo image and a right text block, just use `text-align: justify` to force the logo to the left and the text to the right.

To get this to work, you need at least two rows in the `#header`.

To generate a second row, use a pseudo element: `#header:after` which will place a 100% wide empty inline-block after the date.  The `width: 100%` forces it to start and fill a 2nd row and the `vertical-align: top` gets rid of the extra white space below the baseline.

To deal with the white space in the height, set `line-height: 0` in `#header` which will allow the height of the pseudo-element to collapse to 0.  However, you need to reset the `line-height: 1.5` in `#dates` to get legible text.

**Pros and Cons**

With this approach, the elements will eventually wrap to two lines as the page width gets smaller.

If you want to keep the elements on a single line, you might be better off using CSS tables.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/3U3w4/

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: flex;` property you can set items to horizontally and vertically center.

[Example](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Comment: Having issues setting one item to be left aligned and another on the other side as right aligned... can you offer an example of this?

Comment: @sprocket12 in that case you would also add `justify-content: space-between`. Here's a flex cheat-sheet: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way for vertical align is using `css:display-table` and `css"display-table-cell` properties. If you want align to right content in id="dates" you should use `css:display-inline-table` inside this block.

```
#header {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: table;
}
#logo {
    display: table-cell;
}
#dates {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #696969;
}
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dosandk/qkj4D/)