# Showing an selectlist with corresponding image in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I wish to show a selectlist and an image side by side..

As the values in the selectlist changes the image would change as well.

I tried something like this but does not work..

```
<p>Locales: <select data-bind="options: locales, selectedOptions: selected, optionsCaption: 'Select your locale...', optionsText: 'country', optionsValue: 'country'"></select></p>
<p data-bind="text: selected"></p>
//<img data-bind="attr: {src: image, alt: country}" class="photoThumbnail"/>

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.locales = [
   { country: 'USA', image: 'en_US.jpg' },
   { country: 'Spain', image: 'es_ES.jpg' },
   { country: 'French', image: 'fr_FR.jpg' }
  ]
  self.selected = ko.observable('USA');
 }
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

One thing that needs to be ensured is that all images are loaded at once such that there is no lag while a user changes the selectlist values...

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the 'selectedOptions' binding handler if your  isn't a multiselect. Also try not to specify the 'optionsValue' binding if you're going to use the whole object. It would only leave you writing lots of necessary code:
take a look @ this documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

As for the side by side take look @ : [How to align an inline-block horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572028/how-to-align-an-inline-block-horizontally-and-vertically)

Here's you modified code. Hope it helps:

Make sure the image urls are correct

```js
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.locales = [{
        country: 'USA',
        image: 'en_US.jpg'
    }, {
        country: 'Spain',
        image: 'es_ES.jpg'
    }, {
        country: 'French',
        image: 'fr_FR.jpg'
    }]
    self.selected = ko.observable('USA');
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>Locales:
    <select data-bind="options: locales, value: selected, optionsCaption: 'Select your locale...', optionsText: 'country'"></select>
</p>
<div data-bind="with: selected">
    <p data-bind="text: country"></p>//
  <span>Images should point to the correct url or use a base64 string</span>
<img data-bind="attr: {src: image, alt: image}" class="photoThumbnail" />
</div>
```